# Querying Tumblr Tags through OAuth.io Unauthorized

Tags: oauth, tumblr, oauth.io

I'm getting a 401 unauthorized error

```json
{ "meta": { "status": 401, "msg": "Not Authorized" }, "response": [] }
```

when trying to load Tumblr tags through [OAuth.io](http://www.oauth.io) as follows:

```js
OAuth.popup('tumblr', {cache:true}).done(function(api) { 
    console.log("Successfully OAuthed")

    api.get("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/tagged?tag=lol").done(function(results) {
        console.log(results);
    })
});
```

All other queries work fine. If I query for `/user/dashboard`, for example, the logged in user's dashboard is successfully returned.

Comment: `/v2/user/info` is the only call working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding your api_key to the `api.get`

```
api.get("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/tagged?tag=lol&api_key={consumer_key}").done(function(results) {
  console.log(results);
})
```